# Solr suggester no results

Tags: apache, solr

I want to use the Solr suggester component for city names. I have the following settings:

### schema.xml

Field definition

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The field i want to apply the suggester on

```
<field name="city" type="string"  indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

The copy field

```
<copyField source="city" dest="citySuggest"/>
```

The field

```
<field name="citySuggest" type="textSuggest" stored="false" indexed="true" />
```

### solr-config.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>



<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>    
    <str name="field">citySuggest</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Then i run

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/company/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=Ath&suggest.build=true
```

to build the suggest component

Finally i run

```
   http://localhost:8983/solr/company/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=Ath
```

but i get an empty result set

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0},"suggest":{"mySuggester":{"Ath":{"numFound":0,"suggestions":[]}}}}
```

Are there any obvious mistakes? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Τry the following:

1. In the field with name="citySuggest" set the attribute stored="true".
2. Then rebuild the suggester.

Comment: In fact it is clear in the documentation but i did not notice that. "To be used as the basis for a suggestion, the field must be stored"